# Chat box on parent site showing conversation from the future

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

The chat preview box on Super User, which shows who has recently talked in rooms which the user is currently in, seems to be caught in a rift of the space-time continuum. Several times today I have noticed it saying that a user will speak in anywhere from 0 to 20 seconds. I took a screenshot as an example:

[image: In the future]

I'm not sure if the time isn't synchronized between the chat site and the main site or if there's something else causing it, but it is certainly a bit eerie being told that I will talk in 15 seconds.

Comment: That sounds like a feature not a bug. Question is... do you actually talk in the 15 seconds? Maybe it is giving you a command.

Comment: The title is awesome! +1!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, looks like db1 was not correctly pointing to our internal NTP source -- fixed.