# Was the 30-day waiting period between name changes lifted?

Tags: bug, status-completed, display-names

I was just able to change my display name on Meta. I last did this about 24 days ago I think, but certainly not more than 28 days ago. Has the restriction that you must wait 30 days between name changes been lifted? Or is this a bug?

Comment: There's a short grace period for when you immediately change a name - so if no one comes up with an official answer in a couple hours, I'll re-change my Server Fault name and see if it goes through.

Comment: @GraceNote: [That period is 15 minutes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38257/time-left-until-i-can-change-my-display-name-keeps-randomly-changing/38405#38405) -- I just changed my name so we'll see if I can change it again in 10 minutes...

Comment: @Theoy Hah! Not if my 15 minutes hits first! Though that'll require some crazy amount of chronomanipulation... but this is Stack Overflow! We're *rife* with a disregard for temporal stability! ♪

Comment: @GraceNote: I win! And yes, this seems to be broken.

Comment: @Theun (again) Hah, you can't even *tell* that I already changed my Server Fault name. I'll steal victory by having done it in the future *in the past*! At least, by claiming that I did such.

Comment: @GraceNote: That's a good point, LOL

Comment: I just changed my name so we'll see if I can change it again in 10 minutes... 9... 8... 7... 6... 5... 4... 3... 2... 1...

Comment: And yes, reproduced the problem... I just changed my name again.

Comment: I can see from your history that this is confirmed (and you had changed to The Mountain Exception on the 8th, by the way). Wonder if it's because the few people who used to change every other day are mostly inactive now. Or maybe it's just a bug.

Comment: All this talk of temporal instability reminds me of my favorite bug report I've ever submitted: [Chat box on parent site showing conversation from the future](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73169/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enjoy your power while it lasts :)

This bug is fixed in the next build.

Comment: I have enjoyed this @balpha... [I have enjoyed it indeed...](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/611988#611988)